# Log In MIME type (‘text/html’) not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: html, css, angular

Here is my code snippet I used for my index.html

[image]

But whenever I run this application I get below error

[image]

Please help

Here is my .angular-cli.json file. It might be some with this code snippet. I tried to figure it out but couldn't. \can somebody help -

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "retro-build-con"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI? If so, please add your `angular.json` file.

Comment: @user184994 I do have .angular-cli.json file. Yes, I created my project by ng new

Comment: That's it, can you edit your question to include it? If you want the files within `css` to be served, you need to amend your `angular-cli.json` file, otherwise your routing will return an HTML page

Comment: Add all vas to assets folder, change the references to these scripts in index.html and restart ng serve

Comment: @user184994 Hi thanks for the quick revert. \please see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the CSS file you're trying to load is getting redirected to the HTML page (probably due to the routing).

You need to modify the `assets` block like so:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "css"
  ],
```

This way, the CSS directory will serve it's static contents correctly

Alternately, you can move the CSS directory *inside* the assets directory, and change your path to:

```
href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Once you've made the change, make sure to stop call `ng serve` again to restart the dev server

Comment: @chikun Is the browser error message still `refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/bootstrap.min.css'`?

Comment: Then it sounds like you've not updated the href tag, as the path is still missing `assets` (for the second solution)

Comment: Right.. after updating the href tag the error looks like this now - Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/vendors/owl_carousel/owl.carousel.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Comment: You will also need to move the `vendors` directory (as you did with the `css` directory), and also update any paths as well to add the `assets` prefix

Comment: Buddy you are savior for the night. That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. _/\_